# Python - Files were not saved after writing it

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I am trying this code as I am learning how to scrap all the images from online site. This is the code I obtained it from a book, the program is able to run smoothly without any errors but the issue is that after running the code there isn't any images saved in the folder 'xkcd' . I have already look through it for hours but I still could not figure it out so would like to seek assistance on what have I overlooked. Any assistance is much appreciated.

```
import requests, os, bs4

url = 'http://xkcd.com'              # starting url
os.makedirs('xkcd', exist_ok=True)   # store comics in ./xkcd
while not url.endswith('1790/'):
# Download the page.
print('Downloading page %s...' % url)
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
# Find the URL of the comic image.
comicElem = soup.select('#comic img')

if comicElem == []:
     print('Could not find comic image.')
else:
    try:
        comicUrl = 'http:' + comicElem[0].get('src')
        # Download the image.
        print('Downloading image %s...' % (comicUrl))
        res = requests.get(comicUrl)
        res.raise_for_status()

    except requests.exceptions.MissingSchema:
        # skip this comic
        prevLink = soup.select('a[rel="prev"]')[0]
        url = 'http://xkcd.com' + prevLink.get('href')
        continue
   # Save the image to ./xkcd.
   imageFile = open(os.path.join('xkcd', os.path.basename(comicUrl)), 'wb')
   for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
        imageFile.write(chunk)
        imageFile.close()

# Get the Prev button's url.
prevLink = soup.select('a[rel="prev"]')[0]
url = 'http://xkcd.com' + prevLink.get('href')
print('Done.')
```

Edited: The above code works well now.

Comment: I'm not sure your formatting is right; nothing after the `continue` statement will be run and therefore no file saved

Comment: Can you check your indentation? Right now your file writing is in your exception handling and after a `continue`.

Comment: If this code is the same as what you're running, the file saving only happens when a `MissingSchema` exception is raised. You have to move that out of the `except` block.

Comment: Thanks JCVan, you are right, it's solved.

Comment: This is from Chapter 11 of Al Sweigart's excellent [Automate The Boring Stuff](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/). If you go to the publisher's [page](https://www.nostarch.com/automatestuff) for this book, you can download all of the scripts from the book (including this one)

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` should probably read:

```
if comicElem == []:
     print('Could not find comic image.')
else:
    try:
        comicUrl = 'http:' + comicElem[0].get('src')
        # Download the image.
        print('Downloading image %s...' % (comicUrl))
        res = requests.get(comicUrl)
        res.raise_for_status()

        # Save the image to ./xkcd.
        imageFile = open(os.path.join('xkcd', os.path.basename(comicUrl)), 'wb')
        for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
        imageFile.write(chunk)
        imageFile.close()

    except requests.exceptions.MissingSchema:
        # skip this comic
        prevLink = soup.select('a[rel="prev"]')[0]
        url = 'http://xkcd.com' + prevLink.get('href')
        continue
```

I'm not entirely sure why you were trying to save the file inside an exception handler, but regardless the 'continue' statement will have meant that the actual save code was never being run.

Answer (score 0):

Your writing operation should be within the try block.